# About jQuery append and automatic deleting

Tags: javascript, jquery

When you append by using an existing content, jQuery will delete the
orignal:

```
$(new).append($('#ori'));
```

Then the orignal `$('#ori')` in the document will be deleted, is this by
design?

Comment: It isn't deleted, it's moved to the new location.

Comment: yes, it's moved to the new place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$(new).append($("#ori").clone());
```

if you want to keep the original.

Answer (score 0):

[Yes](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.appendChild)

> Adds a node to the end of the list of
>   children of a specified parent node.
>   If the node already exists it is
>   removed from current parent node, then
>   added to new parent node.

---

If you want to keep the original element, use [cletus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1384967/about-jquery-append-and-automatic-deleting/1384977#1384977)' code.